# Jackson: get the property name where the object is placed

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to deserialize a JSON file, but I got the situation that I have to know which property is placed my deserializing object.

Look at this example:

```json
{
    ...(other properties)...
    "myPropertyName": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": 123
    }
}
```

And I want to know what is the property name where the object is placed (in this case, "myPropertyName"):

```java
class MyObject {
    @SomeAnnotation?
    private String propertyName; // should get myPropertyName
    private String foo; // bar
    private Integer baz; // 123
    // ...getters, setters...
}
```

Any guest?

EDIT:
If helps to understand, think I'm deserializing a Map, and the json above is stored in rootStr variable:

```java
new ObjectMapper().readValue(rootStr, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, MyObject>>() {})
```

Comment: It's not very clear... can you share one level more of the Json and one level more of the code you use to parse?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, the edit helps?

Comment: Does it mean that your Json contains a collection of String (the keys) and MyObject (so always the same object), and what you want is to serialize myObject so that it contains the key value inside the additional property "propertyName"?